# Python Ttkinter project not working when converted to .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

i have created a small mining bot for minecraft and for user friendliness (for my friends) i used Tkinter for the app. When i run my app in python it works great, just as expected, but when i turn it into an .exe file (using PyInstaller) it suddenly doesn't work anymore. It just opens a random console and hides the console after a few seconds. To convert my file to .exe i used the following command in the command prompt: "python -m PyInstaller test.py" or "python -m PyInstaller test.py --onefile". Does anybody have any idea whats going on? For anyone interested, here is the code. Any help is appreciated!

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui

from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk

delay = 5

# program

def INIT():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Minecraft Mining Bot")

    Stop_Key_Button = tk.StringVar()
    Stop_Key_Button.set("i")

    Greeting_Label = tk.Label(
        text="Hello, user! To start using this program, please make sure to enter your stop key on your keyboard. Goodluck!",
        foreground="white",
        background="black"
    )
    Greeting_Label.pack()

    Set_Key_Label = tk.Label(
        text="Your current stop key is:",
        foreground="white",
        background="black"
    )
    Set_Key_Label.pack()

    Display_Key = tk.Label(
        textvariable=Stop_Key_Button,
        foreground="white",
        background="black"
    )
    Display_Key.pack()

    Set_Key_Input = tk.Button(
        text="Click on this to enter your new key",
        foreground="white",
        background="black",
        command = lambda: SET_KEYBIND(Stop_Key_Button)
    )
    Set_Key_Input.pack()

    Start_Button_Label = tk.Label(
        text="To start the bot, press the button below. You then have 5 seconds to open minecraft and it will start! To stop the bot please press your button you put in.",
        foreground="white",
        background="black"
    )
    Start_Button_Label.pack()

    Start_Button = tk.Button(
        text="Click on this to start the bot with a 5 second delay!",
        foreground="white",
        background="black",
        command = lambda: START_ROBOT(delay, Stop_Key_Button)
    )
    Start_Button.pack()

    window.mainloop()


def SET_KEYBIND(Stop_Key_Button):
    while (1):
        key = keyboard.read_key()
        if (key != None):
            Stop_Key_Button.set(key)
            print(Stop_Key_Button.get())
            return



def START_ROBOT(delay, Stop_Key_Button):

    sleep(delay)

    keyboard.press("ctrl")
    keyboard.press("w")
    pyautogui.mouseDown()

    while(1):
        if(keyboard.is_pressed(Stop_Key_Button.get())):

            keyboard.release("w")
            keyboard.release("ctrl")
            pyautogui.mouseUp()

            break

        sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    INIT()
```

Comment: add --windowed flag to pyinstaller

Comment: The console comes up with an error and closes, try to capture the error in it. Maybe screen record and freeze on the frame with the error and you could fix it up

Answer (score 1):

use this command to convert it to exe with gui support and without console

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico app.py
```

if you want tkinter default icon, remove `--icon=icon.ico`

Comment: So, i tried both options (with icon and without) and it still does not do anything. I do have to point out that if i do pyinstaller.exe it says it doesnt recognize it so i tried it with "python -m PyInstaller" and your arguments. Just a loading icon at my curser for 2-3 sec when i open the file and nothing happens. Thanks for the effort but for some reason it still does not like me xD

Comment: I converted your code successfully. At first I tried with VSCode terminal and it got your error. So I open windows terminal and cd to the project path and used the command and worked :)

Comment: Saying either `--windowed` or `--noconsole` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Aparently it was actually my fault, in short: i used the wrong python script (i was working with multiple but i only wanted to convert 1 file). I accidently kept converting a file with only 5 lines of code and not the file i actually wanted to convert. Thanks for the help because else i didint know all those arguments!

So in the end i only used `python -m PyInstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico main.py`